# How to get the value of populated text input field in a data table column

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a data table that I populate text fields in a column for every row. I tried to get the value from these text fields but it always take the first column's text field value since as I assume id is always the same for every text field populated. How can I solve this issue ? Do I have to also populate dynamic id names for every text field ? I am getting the value with jQuery by the way.

With this piece of code:

```
var qty = $("#input").val();
```

And I am going to send this "qty" variable to a php code via an Ajax call.
Ajax call is working fine, sending the variable, I have checked it so it is not the problem.

Table declaration code:

```
var table3 =  $("#last3").DataTable({

                                    "columnDefs": [
                                {
                                "targets": 4,
                                "data": null,
                                "defaultContent": '<input id="input" type="number"  value="" min="1" max="9"></input>'
                                },

                                {
                                "targets": 3,
                                "data": null,
                                "defaultContent": '<input type="button" value="Add" class="btn-add" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></input>'
                                },

                                { "searchable": false, "targets": 0 } ],

                                select:false,

                                "scrollY": "32vh",
                                "scrollCollapse": true,
                                "paging": false,
                            });
```

EDIT 1: I have this piece of code, this dynamically create a cell value and increment it by one, so basically creates an index column. I just wonder is there a way to modify this so that instead of populating the cell.innerhtml, populates the "id" attribute somehow. so this way I would have unique id attr for each text field. (does not have to be id though, I can also get the value by "name" attr.)

```
table3.column(4, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {cell.innerHTML = i+1;}
```

Comment: If you're going to be getting all of the values, you could give all of the inputs the same class, and then iterate through all of the matched classes with `$('.someclass').each(function(){ .... });`

Comment: Inside your iterator you have the cell param, you can search inside that to find your input, and then if you need to change the id of element, you can use `$(input).attr('id', ($(input).attr('id') + i));`

Comment: @GiovanCruz Hey thanks, I tried this and new code is `table3.column(4, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) { $(input).attr('id', ($(input).attr('id') + i));` but I guess `var qty = $("#input").val();` code has to be updated too and I got stuck there. Since the ids are created dynamically, first I need to get the 'id' attributes from the text fields and pass it to the code as a variable like `var qty = $("#"+id").val();` , right ?, I tried this but the id attr seemed to be undefined when I alert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the button add after table draw, because of paging, searching etc. And as i sayied in comments, inside your iterator you have the cell param, you can search inside that to find your input, and then deal with it.

Maybe this help you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var table3 = $("#last3").DataTable({

    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 4,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": '<input id="input" type="number" class="table-input"  value="" min="1" max="9"></input>'
      },

      {
        "targets": 3,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": '<input type="button" value="Add" class="btn-add" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></input>'
      },

      {
        "searchable": false,
        "targets": 0
      }
    ],

    select: false,

    "scrollY": "32vh",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
  }).on('draw.dt', function() {
    $("#last3 tr").on("click", ".btn-add", function() {
      var data = table3.DataTable().row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
      console.log(data);
    })
  });


  table3.column(4, {
    search: 'applied',
    order: 'applied'
  }).nodes().each(function(cell, i) {
    var $input = $(cell).find('input');
    $input.attr({
      'id': ($input.attr('id') + i),
      'value': i
    });
  }).draw();;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>



<table id="last3" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 Data 3</td>
      <td>Row 1 Data 4</td>
      <td>Row 1 Data 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 2 Data 3</td>
      <td>Row 2 Data 4</td>
      <td>Row 2 Data 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 3 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 3 Data 3</td>
      <td>Row 3 Data 4</td>
      <td>Row 3 Data 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 4 Data 2</td>
      <td>Row 4 Data 3</td>
      <td>Row 4 Data 4</td>
      <td>Row 4 Data 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, I deleted the `value: i` stuff because it filled up the text field with iterated numbers too :). Now it is working fine. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Oh yeah sure, I am new here so just missed it, excuse me. I have marked it ! Thank you again.